# localhost URLs should be allowed for block quotes

Tags: bug, blockquote, link-validator

Suppose I want to ask a question about some code that doesn't work and need to quote the following error message

> There was no endpoint listening at http://localhost.here/Magic that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Now if I use "code" formatting (either prepending with whitespaces or quotes) there's no problem. Yet if I use a quote block (prepended with `>`) I'll get an error message saying that links cannot contain `localhost`, I have to wrap those in code blocks.

The deal is the error message I wanted to quote isn't really code, it's actually a quote. Also it's a very long text and so using code block will disable auto-wrapping at end of lines which isn't very convenient.

Could you please change the behavior so that `http://localhost` links are allowed in `>` quotes?

Comment: Could this error not equally contain a non-localhost URL? What do you propose then? *One* solution would be to not link URLs which don't resolve, rather than blocking them completely... Not that I'm a fan of that suggestion, just offering an alternative.

Comment: That's not a bug in my view btw, pretty sure it's [by-design].

Comment: +1. This bug forces me to use code block for log fragments or firebug header dumps, which is (I think) not semantically correct.

Answer (score 2):

Why not simply do this?

> Can't find endpoint `http://localhost/pipe/Endpoint`

Markdown:

```
> Can't find endpoint `http://localhost/pipe/Endpoint`
```

You don't really want that URL to be clickable. Message length isn't an issue, though long URLs are a bit of a pain.

> There was no endpoint listening at `net.pipe://localhost/Magic`, nor is there one listening on `http://localhost/this/is/really/annoying/but/sometimes/URLs/are/just/way/too/long/to/format/in/any/sensible/way/sorry`, that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

If the actual URL parameters/path/whatever aren't crucial, you could shorten it so as to male it a bit less visually distracting:

> There was no endpoint listening at `net.pipe://localhost/Magic`, nor is there one listening on `http://localhost/this/is/re[...]ay/sorry`, that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Comment: What if the message is very long? Auto-wrapping will be off and I'll have to insert linebreaks.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean - a super-long URL?

Comment: I've added one into the question. I hope that one is clear.

Comment: Clear but I don't see a problem.

Comment: @sharptooth: You can see the [source](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/bf48eab0-37f4-4527-a32d-c1c8cc6d1467/view-source) of Mat's post to see he's only encoding the URL as code using "`", not the whole quote (if that's where the confusion lies...)

Comment: @Matt: Nice, I didn't notice that.

Comment: Okay, I didn't immediately notice the nice workaround you suggested. I outlined it in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The workaround is to use `>` for the whole error message so that it is rendered as a quote and then mark the URL inside the text as code block like in [the other answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/181655/132564):

> There was no endpoint listening at `http://localhost/Magic` that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Note that here only the URL becomes a code block, the rest of the text is a quote and is auto-wrapped and gets all the applicable perks.